# Applying the fluid pressure equation on gases

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

The pressure exerted by a fluid at depth is given by:

$$ P = \rho g h$$

The state variables in an ideal gas are related by:

$$ PV = nRT$$

For the second equation, we assume the system is in equilibrium and the state variables are constant throughout the whole container which has the gas. If this is so, then how can we combine the first equation with the second? Since the first equation suggests that pressure is no longer uniform.

I mention this because it is used as a component for solving an irodov problem and user dnaik has said in this [stack post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/585500/236734)  that we can use the equation this way because the assumptions of the fluid pressure equation are less than that of the ideal gas equation.. However, they make contradictory statements.

So, the question boils down to if we can really apply the fluid pressure model onto an ideal gas, and if so, why? Or is there some misunderstanding that I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are dealing with a compressible ideal gas, the correct fluid equation to use is $$\frac{dp}{dh}=\rho g$$subject to the boundary condition $p=p_0$ at h = 0.  So combining the fluid equation with the ideal gas law gives $$\frac{dp}{dh}=\frac{pM}{RT}g$$where M is the molecular weight.

If you are dealing with a liquid, the correct equation of state approximation is $$\rho=\rho_0\exp{\left[\frac{P-P_0}{K}-\alpha (T-T_0)\right]}$$where K is the bulk modulus and $\alpha$ is the volumetric coefficient of thermal expansion.  The fluid pressure equation in this case is the same as for the case of an ideal gas.

Comment: I'm still confused, shouldn't the whole container have uniform pressure for equilibrium? (for gases)  the first equation gives a pressure gradient with depth.

Comment: For example we do $ P_{ext} \approx P_{in}$ and then express as $ P_{in}$ use ideal gas law, this suggests that the pressure at each point in gas it same instead of having pressure gradient

Comment: For static/thermodynamic equilibrium in a gravitational field, the pressure of the fluid below must support the weight of all the fluid above.  So since the amount of fluid above varies with depth, the pressure must vary with depth.  in the case of an ideal gas or other compressible fluid, the density will also vary with depth as a consequence of the pressure variations.  If density is varying with depth, which density are you supposed to use in the static equilibrium equation?  Well, you need to integrate the equilibrium equation differentially with respect to the density variations.

Comment: Wait a second, so if I take differential cylindrical volume elements of the container then I can apply the ideal gas law to it but not to the whole container, correct? If so, I'd suggest adding this point into the answer because it helps a lot.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Usually this effect is negligible in a laboratory sized container of gas.  But think of how it applies to the atmoephere.

Answer (score 0):

> The pressure exerted by a fluid at depth is given by:

Should be read instead as "the pressure exerted by a fluid at depth *due to its own weight*".  We may consider the pressure at a depth to be both that from the weight of that fluid plus any external pressure.

Most gases and gas vessels have very small values for $\rho$ and $h$, so the pressure difference from the top to the bottom of the vessel is a small fraction of the total pressure, and often ignored.

1atm is close to 100000Pa.  The pressure difference of air between the top and bottom of a 1m vessel is about 12Pa.

Comment: That makes sense but how can we use ideal gas law if there is a pressure graident throughout the container

Comment: In the above example, the difference is about 0.01%.  Unless the other parameters have uncertainties less than that, there is no issue.  Often temperature will vary by more than the pressure will.  Also, most gases differ from ideal by more than that amount.  It would be on a case-by-case basis whether it would be better to approximate an average pressure, or if you need to sum the effects from multiple sub-volumes where the pressure (and other variables) are known more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can apply the ideal gas law for differential volume elements (small enough for constant pressure throughout) but they are inapplicable for the whole container.